# Create an SSH tunnel starting from the jump server

Tags: ssh, security, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I have this server that I don't own so I cannot register new users or new authorized keys but I have to temporary share my access with a different user. I don't want to share my username and password.

Is it possible to create a new tunnel starting from my machine? In this scenario my machine will act as a Jump Server but it's the Jump server that instantiate the connection.

In this way I can always stop the connection and I don't have to share my credentials.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you wish for someone else to login into the server, without creating a user for them? Are you sure this is allowed? Sharing personal accounts can be a serious breach of security.

Comment: Yes I need exactly that. The owner of the destination server is informed I’m legally allowed to do that but it’s temporary and I don’t want to share my account that I will use in the future with someone that needs to use the server one or two times

Comment: An SSH multi-hop still requires authentication to the first server, so the other user would still need to authenticate to it, regardless if they do it or if you're already logged in to the first server prior to initiating the multi-hop _(keep in mind if that connection terminates on your end, so does the multi-hop)_. You can likely configure a port redirect for the other user to connect to the tunnel, but this scenario is far from recommended.

Comment: `my machine will act as a Jump Server but it's the Jump server that instantiate the connection` – Both ways? I.e. to the target server *and* to the machine where the different user is? Can you ssh to the latter machine as well?

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski Well no I don't think that we need both ways. We just want to connect using an SSH shell or SFTP

Comment: Must the server see your IP and credentials? Or the credentials only? (2) Can the other user ssh to your machine? Or can you ssh to their machine? I'm thinking of authenticating them to you, so you don't give access (e.g. an open port or a forwarded agent) to everyone. Or can they open a port? (3) Do you authenticate to the server with a key? If not, can you? Can you add a new key to `authorized_keys` on the server?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to start a SOCKS5 proxy. This way, they wouldn't have to log on as you. Instead they'd be using your proxy to jump from their box thru it and to a place only you can get to.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1642419/642390) includes instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

safest bet with the least amount of setup would be to use screen multiuser.

http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser